# Joining two similar tables in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, union

I have two tables with similar columns - let's say table A with column LABEL_A
and table B with column LABEL_B. The data types of LABEL_A and LABEL_B are same.

How can I select LABELs from both tables in a single query? (So the the result of the query contains single column LABEL containing data from LABEL columns of both tables).

EDIT: Can I use such UNION queries in a CURSOR?

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT a.label_a
  FROM TABLE_A a
UNION ALL
SELECT b.label_b
  FROM TABLE_B b
```

`UNION ALL` will be faster, but won't remove duplicates if they exist.  Use `UNION` if you want duplicates removed.

Comment: Works, thanks. And what if I want to assign the resulting UNIONed column a name?

Comment: @NumberFour: Alias the column appropriately in the statement before the UNION [All].  IE: `SELECT a.label_a AS labelx` - don't need to define an alias for columns after the UNION.

Comment: And can I use the UNION in the CURSOR?

Comment: @NumberFour: I don't see anything in the documentation that suggests you can't use a `UNION` in a cursor: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Answer (score 3):

Use a [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/union.html):

```
select LABEL_A as Label from A
union
select LABEL_B as Label from B
```