# data from two tables and one show

Tags: php, mysql, database, doctrine

I have two similar table in database, for example:

news1:

```
id | title | body|
1  | aaa   | aaa |
2  | ggg   | bbb |
2  | xxx   | ccc |
```

and
news2:

```
id | title | body | photo |
1  | BBB   | 111  | 111
2  | RRR   | 222  | 222
3  | EEE   | 333  | 333
```

how can i get data  from two tables and show in template for example order by title?

```
title | body | photo
aaa   | aaa
BBB   | 111  | 111
EEE   | 333  | 333
ggg   | ggg
RRR   | 222  |222
xxx   | xxx
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Union

```
SELECT *
  FROM news1 n1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
  FROM news2 n2
```

UNION ALL will be faster, but won't remove duplicates if they exist. Use UNION if you want duplicates removed.
[Joining two similar tables in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640428/joining-two-similar-tables-in-mysql)